# How to pass command line parameters in a python test

Tags: python, oop, testing, decorator, python-decorators

I have a microservice class MsActionDetector. It takes an argument from the command line because the ms is launched within a .sh script, both locally and inside a container.

```
class MsActionDetector(BaseMicroservice):

    def __init__(self):
        self.config = safe_load(open(sys.argv[1]))
        ....
```

I would like to perform integration tests thus instantiating my microservice in a test, but that doesn't work because the class excepts a command line argument. How can I achieve this? Is python Decorator a solution? Should I modify my constructor?

Comment: Why not let your test script start the application from the shell with `os.system('<command goes here>')`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what does os.system() does?

Comment: How do you do your integration tests?

Comment: If you import the os module you can use regular shell commands like 'python myService.py args' to launch other things like a service helper daemon or another application for testing.

Comment: The call os.system seems to be synchronous, I can't do anything else in my test

Answer (score 0):

`sys.argv` is a list with little magic. It is initialized from the command line, but you are free to change it at will. So it is easy to set it to the value you want in the test class before instantiating the `MsActionDetector`:

```
sys.argv = ['cmd', 'path/to/file']
msad = MsActionDetector()     # will open path/to/file
...
```